# Recode variables

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, recode

I'm trying recode some variables using

```
ppar$denr <- recode(ppar$q3c, 0 =c("1"), 1 =c("2"), 2 =c("5"), 3 = c("4", "11"), 4 = c("3","6", "7", "10", "12", "77"))
```

It return this error

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "ppar$denr <- recode(ppar$q3c, 0 ="
```

I try use `<-` but return

```
 invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

Comment: you want 3 and 4 to be encoded by vector of multiple values ?

Answer (score 0):

In R syntax, names that start with numbers are non-syntactic and must be quoted:

```r
dplyr::recode(factor(1:5), "1" = "A")
#> [1] A 2 3 4 5
#> Levels: A 2 3 4 5
```

In terms of the data, `1` is a value, not a name, but as the function `recode` is structured, it's used as a name.

Side note: Making factors of numbers is not a good idea, as factors are integers internally, so factors of numbers cause confusion whether operations are happening on the levels or the underlying integers.

Comment: Do you recommend that I change to factor after the recode ?

Comment: No; I though that's what you already had. If it's a character vector, that's less bad, but you should still convert to numeric/integer at some point. Better, start there.

Comment: So, the variable is double but when I trying convert to factor, return this error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, abor, value = integer(0)) :    `

Comment: Don't convert numbers to factors; see the note in the answer. But there's something wrong with your call; does it work without assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by `memisc` package:

```
memisc::recode(ppar$q3c,
         0 <- 1,
         1 <- 2,
         2 <- 5,
         3 <- c(4, 11))
```

Or by `car`:

```
car::recode(ppar$q3c, "1 = 0; 2 = 1; 5 = 2; c(4, 11) = 3")
```

Comment: I'm using `library(memisc)`, than you I corrected the sintax and the code running